# Jackson - Deserialize Interface to enum

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an interface `Event` and multiple enums that implement this interface (`UserEvent`, `BusinessEvent`, etc).

I want to deserialize the following json data:

```
{
  "event" : "SIGNUP"
}
```

To this bean:

```
public class Input
{ 
   private Event event;

   public Event getEvent() {..}
   public void setEvent(Event event) {..}
}

public enum UserEvent implements Event
{
    SIGNUP;
}
```

Here, i'd like event to be deserialized to `UserEvent.SIGNUP`.

How can I accomplish this? Reading up on `@JsonTypeInfo` seems to indicate that an additional `type` attribute would be needed, but in this case, there's just one string which maps directly to an enum value.

Comment: Are all of implementations of `Event` known at build time or they can change during runtime?

Comment: What if two enum classes define a constant with the same name?

Comment: @rkosegi They are known.

Comment: @MauricePerry I'll make sure that doesn't happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `Event` interface for field `event` in `Input` and jackson doesn't know anything about `UserEvent` as implementation of this interface.

You can use custom `JsonDeserializer` to get value:

```
public interface Event {
}

public static class Input
{
    private Event event;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = EventDeserializer.class)
    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }
}

public enum UserEvent implements Event
{
    SIGNUP;
}

public static class EventDeserializer  extends StdDeserializer<Event> {

    protected EventDeserializer() {
        super(Event.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Event deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return UserEvent.valueOf(p.getText());
    }
}

@Test
public void converEnum() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Input input = objectMapper.readValue("{\n" +
            "  \"event\" : \"SIGNUP\"\n" +
            "}", Input.class);

    Assert.assertThat(input.getEvent(), Matchers.is(UserEvent.SIGNUP));
}
```

Comment: Does this solution back you into the corner of only being able to use a single concrete implementation for the `Event` field? Since you annotate the getter for the `Event` field with the `UserEventDeserializer`, what happens if the concrete value in the Event field is a `BusinessEvent`?

Comment: @mfunaro I don't think so. Even if example is just for UserEvent nothing will stop you to write more sofisticated  code with possible enums values in 'deserilize' method.

Answer (score 2):

For a single enum the jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin generates code like the following:

```
@JsonCreator
public static Foo fromValue(String value) {
    Foo constant = CONSTANTS.get(value);
    if (constant == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(value);
    } else {
        return constant;
    }
}
```

I guess you could write a factory method which is annotated with @JsonCreator and somehow decides which enum to choose. I'm not sure if it matters much where you put this method.

Comment: Where would I specify this method - on the interface itself?

Comment: As I said, I don't know if it matters much. If you use Java SE 8 (recommended) then the interface might be an option.

Comment: I'm on Java 8. But defining it on the interface isn't working - doesn't seem to be getting called

Comment: Using jackson 2.7.6

Answer (score 2):

Having a similar task I ended up creating a custom deserializer:

```
public class IFooDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<IFoo> {

    public IFooDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public IFooDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public IFoo deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String value = p.getCodec().readValue(p, String.class);
        return Stream.of(GoodFoo.values(), BadFoo.values())
                .flatMap(Stream::of)
                .filter(el -> el.name().equals(value))
                .findAny()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Could not deserialize foo: " + value));
    }
}
```